# How to properly route in subdomain , a laravel auth app

Tags: php, laravel, server, cpanel, laravel-7

The problem is this: One subdomain admin.domain.com and a laravel app installed here with auth.
Everything is good until I press login or register button and I get "File not found.". I have ssh control and cpanel control for the server. I read everything on google and stackoverflow but nothing helped me. 
If it helps, I tried to route the registration page to '/' and it works but when I press the register button 'File not found'. To mention that i didn't modified anything, i only create the app via "laravel new App --auth"

So this is working

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```